# How to get Json Array to work inside Asyntask - Android

Tags: arrays, json, for-loop, android-asynctask

I have an `Asynctask` that uses a Json function in the `doInBackground` part. The function collects an array of comments and places them into a variable called `KEY_COMMENTS`. In the `onPreExecute` it places the comments into a textView using a for loop to select each comment individually. The problem is that its not selecting each comment it will only select one. If I set the loop to go for more than 1 time it will crash the app. Here is my code,

```
    class loadComments extends AsyncTask<JSONObject, String, JSONObject> {


            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
                super.onProgressUpdate(values);

            } 

            protected JSONObject doInBackground(JSONObject... params) {
            //do your work here

                JSONObject json2 = CollectComments.collectComments(usernameforcomments, offsetNumber);

                    return json2;



            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json2) {
                try {  
                    if (json2.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) { 
                        registerErrorMsg.setText("");
                        String res2 = json2.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                        if(Integer.parseInt(res2) == 1){ 


                            JSONArray array = json2.getJSONArray(KEY_COMMENT);
                            for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

                                LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                                         commentBox.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.comment_box_bg);
                                        layoutParams.setMargins(0, 10, 0, 10);
                                        commentBox.setPadding(0,0,0,10);
                                         commentBox.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                                         linear.addView(commentBox, layoutParams);


                                        commentBoxHeader.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                                         commentBoxHeader.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.comment_box_bg);
                                        commentBoxHeader.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.comment_box_header);
                                        commentBox.addView(commentBoxHeader);


                                        commentView.setText(array.getString(i));
                                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams commentViewParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                         LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                                        commentViewParams.setMargins(20, 10, 20, 20);
                                        commentView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.comment_bg);
                                         commentView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black)); 
                                        commentBox.addView(commentView, commentViewParams);
                            }



                            }//end if key is == 1
                        else{
                            // Error in registration
                            registerErrorMsg.setText(json2.getString(KEY_ERROR_MSG));
                        }//end else
                    }//end if
                } //end try

                catch (JSONException e) { 
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }//end catch    
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`doInBackGround` : method is used as a Thread !
`onPostExecute` : acts as a UI Thread !

So try to put your any-long running code in , `doInBackGround` method !

When an asynchronous task is executed, the task goes through 4 steps:

**From the [Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)** :

> **onPreExecute()**, invoked on the UI thread before the task is executed. This step is normally used to setup the task, for instance
> by showing a progress bar in the user interface.
>
> **doInBackground(Params...)**, invoked on the background thread immediately after onPreExecute() finishes executing. This step is used
> to perform background computation that can take a long time. The
> parameters of the asynchronous task are passed to this step. The
> result of the computation must be returned by this step and will be
> passed back to the last step. This step can also use
> publishProgress(Progress...) to publish one or more units of progress.
> These values are published on the UI thread, in the
> onProgressUpdate(Progress...) step.
>
> **onProgressUpdate(Progress...)**, invoked on the UI thread after a call to publishProgress(Progress...). The timing of the execution is
> undefined. This method is used to display any form of progress in the
> user interface while the background computation is still executing.
> For instance, it can be used to animate a progress bar or show logs in
> a text field.
>
> **onPostExecute(Result)**, invoked on the UI thread after the background computation finishes. The result of the background
> computation is passed to this step as a parameter.